# How to create a string sensitive if condition?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to make an if statement that returns a message if a specific string is typed in the input box.

```
var ram = 0;
var run = document.getElementById('run');
var r = function() {
  ram++;
  if (ram == 1) {
    var ib = document.getElementById("ib").value + ": logged in type smash to   begin hacking";
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(ib);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("log2").appendChild(node);
  } else
  if (ib.value == "smash" && ram == 2) {
    var node2 = document.createElement("li");
    var textnode2 = document.createTextNode("smash:entering  malware_on3........making alias .....guest accessesing guest...done:)");
    node2.appendChild(textnode2);
    document.getElementById("log2").appendChild(node2);
  }
  run.addEventListener("click", r);
}
```

Comment: What's your question or problem?

Comment: Proper indentation always helps...

Comment: Click, click-click, click-click-click-click, and so on... Is it what you want ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var inputBoxElement = document.getElementById("myInputBox");
if( inputBoxElement.value == "~some string~" ){
    //however you'd like to notify your users
}
```

Not sure if this is what you're looking for...

Answer (score 1):

ib will not contain any value when ram is not equal to one therefore your second else if statement will always be trying to read a value property of undefined, and so you should be seeing console errors when clicking after the first time.

What you need to do is select ib outside the first if statement so it can be used in the second else if statement:

```
var ram = 0;
var run = document.getElementById('run');
var r = function() {
  ram++;
  var ib = document.getElementById("ib");
  if (ram == 1) {
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(ib.value + ": logged in type smash to   begin hacking");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("log2").appendChild(node);
  } else if (ib.value == "smash" && ram == 2) {
    var node2 = document.createElement("li");
    var textnode2 = document.createTextNode("smash:entering  malware_on3........making alias .....guest accessesing guest...done:)");
    node2.appendChild(textnode2);
    document.getElementById("log2").appendChild(node2);
  }
}
run.addEventListener("click", r);
```

Comment: I couldn't figure what he was after, but this by far makes the most sense, he's just made a function that never makes it to his else condition.

I might suggest throwing the `run.addEventListener("click",r);` outside the function as well.